What is an ellipse in infinite-dimensional spaces?
The image of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under a linear transformation is an ellipse. (Let's say that the transformation is invertible to avoid degenerate cases.)
Is there a sense in which this geometric idea makes sense in general (infinite-dimensional) normed vector spaces? Is the image of the unit ball under an invertible bounded linear transformation an ellipse?
From boundedness I know that the image must live inside some new ball whose radius is the operator norm. But what does the image look like inside this new ball?
I realise that this is not a well posed question; I'm essentially asking if there is a way to formulate it properly.

I guess there is no answer to the question: what does the image look like? What does "look like" mean even in 4-dimensional space? But you can certainly establish some properties as you mentioned: it is bounded, it contains a ball of positive radius inside (given that it is invertible). You can also prove that it is convex. But to be properly called an "ellipsoid" it must have infinitely many pairwise perpendicular "axes". For example, if you are in a Hilbert space, and your linear transformation is compact, selfadjoint and positive-definite, then you have something you can call an ellipsoid, with semi-axes of length $=\sqrt{\lambda_i}$, where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of the transformation. The axes themselves correspond to the mutually orthogonal eigenvectors. If you relax some of these restrictions, say if you have continuous spectrum, I am not sure about calling the image of the unit ball an "ellipsoid", but you can of course define the terms at will.

I don't think the invertibility gives you a ball of positive radius inside. I can shrink the n-th dimension by a factor of n, clearly invertible but there is no global minimum.

What do you mean @quarague ? The mapping $\ell^2\to\ell^2$, $x\mapsto (x_n/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is certainly not invertible.

@Jochen Well $x \mapsto nx_n$ is a linear map that inverts the operation but you are correct that this does not map $\mathcal{l}^2$ to $\mathcal{l}^2$.

You can give any definition you want. For example, given a Banach space $V$, you could define an ellipsoid in $V$ to be any set of the form $A(S)+x_0$, where $A\in L(V, V)$ is a bounded invertible linear operator, and $S=\{x\in V\ :\ \lVert x \rVert=1\}$ is the unit sphere of $V$. This definition certainly looks reasonable; another thing is whether it is useful.
(An anecdote. When I was an undergraduate, I had the chance to attend a series of lectures on Functional Analysis by Vitali Milman, a famous great expert in Banach space geometry. He had a quote which I memorized: "Definitions are like pollution. You want to keep them to a minimum, but you can't just eliminate them, since otherwise you would have no industry").
As far as I know, the most important application of the definition of "ellipsoid" in $\mathbb R^n$ is John's theorem and its consequences. It seems to me that all of this is very finite--dimensional, even though it looks like people are very much interested in understanding what happens when the dimensionality becomes very big. I suppose there are studies which deal with ellipsoids in infinite dimensions, thus proving that the above definition is useful to somebody, but I have not been able to find any.
